# Use Lynx to download the source of the page I'm currently on

Tags: lynx

If I have a page open in `Lynx`, how can I download the source (`HTML`) of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the source code by pressing the `\` key (thanks to [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/make-text-browsing-a-snap-with-20-keyboard-shortcuts-for-lynx/))

Then press the `P` key, and then select `Save to a local file`.